# Choosing among a set of data members by type, where each type is used only once

Tags: c++, templates

I have the same class template, C, being parameterized by many different types T as data members in my various Derived classes. However, I know that, in any given derived class, say 'Derived', each T is only used as a parameter once among the data members in Derived. Thus, in principle a method inherited from my Base class, here 'f', should be able to choose exactly one of these parameterized data members when given a type T.

The code below gives an example of what I'm trying to do, but only involving one type:

```
template<typename T>
class C {};

class Base {
    template<typename T>
    void f() {
        // For example, if T is MyType, I want to end up accessing 'instance_for_myType'
    }
};

class Derived : Base {
    C<MyType> instance_for_myType;
};
```

Essentially, I want to be able to look up the data member by its type: derived classes of Base will have their own identifiers for these data members, and it would be wasteful for Base to have to 'switch' among all of them.

Thanks!

**Update**

I will try to clarify my intentions here. I want to leverage the same piece of generic code, f, across every occurrence of the class template C that happens to be in the instance of Derived. If I just had one occurrence across all of my Derived classes, then it would be a simple matter to hard-code its identifier in f and in Base and remove the template on f.

The way I've written the code above is not intended to suggest how I would necessarily actually go about implementing this - it's just a conceptual representation. Essentially, I think, I am trying to "look up" data members by type. If DeadMG is right, then I may be out of luck in this.

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Be an angel and write `;` after each class declaration. This is not Java.

Comment: How exactly do you want to access a member of a derived class from the base class?

Comment: `C` is not a class; it is a class template. `C<MyType>` is a class.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. @jasal, conceptually I was thinking of it as "looking up the data member by type", as if there were (conceptually) some sort of mappping that could be maintained from type to data member.

Comment: Given your "clarifications" so far I'd say that it is very unclear what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't *need* `instance` to be in the derived class, then it sounds to me like this is what you want:

```
template<typename T>
class C {}

template<typename T>
class Base {
    C<T> instance;
    void f() {
        // do stuff with instance
    }
};

class Derived1 : Base<MyType1> {};
class Derived2 : Base<MyType2> {};
// etc.
```

And if you need a common base just add another layer of inheritance; perhaps a `IBase`, for example.

Comment: It's only really CRTP if you pass the derived type as the template parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My aim is to be able to have multiple instances in each Derived class, not just one, so I don't think I would be able to use this.

Comment: @JohnDoe: Your design requirements, such as they are, don't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

> Thus, in principle a method inherited from my Base class, here 'f',
>   should be able to choose exactly one of these parameterized data
>   members when given a type T.

Not in the slightest. You know it, but there's no way in hell the compiler could possibly know it or enforce it or offer a feature for it. Furthermore, the compiler cannot possibly know where in memory the object is located without serious further restrictions on Derived that the language has no way of expressing.

The long and short is that it cannot be done without seriously changing your design parameters.

Comment: I see, your claims make sense. Thanks